# Bootstrap v3 - Input group get separate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble to keep the input group in only one piece:

[image]

Based on the MVC 5 template view build using scaffolding I have build:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Formatos e Planos</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SizeOpenedWidth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SizeOpenedWidth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SizeOpenedWidth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="input-group-addon">x</div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SizeOpenedHeight, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SizeOpenedHeight, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="input-group-addon">mm</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default css comes when you create a new MVC project has `max-width` set to `280px` for all the inputs. That is the reason it messed up your input groups.

[image]

If you remove/make adjustments to this in your `~/Content/Site.css`, You should be good.

Comment: Hi thanks! It solve the problem, thank you for your help :)